# How to Override rules and decision tables in Drools 6?

Tags: drools

There is a scenario where we have set of master rules. One of the rules is similar to below rule:

```
rule "Check Eligibility"
when 
    $response(type=="rest",age== 25)
then 
   $response.setSendLetter("Y");
   $response.setUpdateStatus("eligible");
end
```

These rules will be available to customers. We want our customers to be able to customise the rule. If decide not to customise, then rule should apply for them. Customising could be adding additional conditions in "when" or could be overriding the existing conditions and also adding or modify the "when" part. They can also add to "then" part of the rule.

Something like:

```
rule "Check Eligibility"
when 
   $response(type=="rest",age== 27, state="IL")
then 
   $response.setSendLetter("N");
   $response.setUpdateStatus("eligible");
   $response.setSendEmail("Y");
end
```

We also have some decision tables which need similar customisation.

From rules there was initial suggestion to use "extends" but from what I know "extends" works as "AND" where it will check conditions on both parent and child and if both are true it will do "then" part.

The possible solution I could think off is to clone the master repository for each customer and then whenever there is change in master repository rule, we do a pull onto the customer repositories. The possible issue could be occasional merge conflicts that may have to be resolved manually.

The clone solution hasn't been accepted in the team, so wanted to know what are possible solutions to achieve "override" for both rules and decision tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a technical issue and a managerial issue.

If you management decided to let customers mess around with rules they must be aware of the consequences. Apparently customers are not to be left alone with their rules but your organization continues to be responsible for the unblemished function of the entire application. *You won't be able to do that for free, and the more leeway customers have, the more expensive it will get.*

There is no comfortable technical solution for this. Extension is unfit for the kind of modifications you have described: rules must be replaced.

1. You can (as you have written) copy the DRL file (create a branch in your CM system) and let the customer edit. This is a clean approach; you can test the customer's baseline with additional tests (another CM item to be branched) and deploy using well-known CM techniques.
2. An alternative would be to let the customer write another DRL file containing the rules that need to be changed. But you cannot compile this DRL file along with the original one; duplicating rules isn't permitted. There are workarounds, e.g., by replacing rules in the compiled KiePackages, or disabling overridden rules in the KieBase, but they have the unsavoury implication of requiring the use of the non-stable internal API.
3. You might try and define a subset of the DRL language customers are permitted to use and let rules be written and overwritten using some DSL based on the subset, perhaps in XML or similar. Then, a generator can check the data and create the DRL text. With this approach, overriding is a simple feature, to be handled by the generator. But there's considerable development work required.

As far as decision tables written as spreadsheets on Excel files are concerned you'll need to clone anyway. I can't think of any other solution for modifications in such rule sets.

Comment: Thanks @laune ! Appreciate very explanatory reply. Yes, #1 is what I want to go with, considering we have to be live in 2 months from now. Also we have decision tables which anyway have to be copied. We also have plans to come up with custom UI where we only expose rules written in "Domain-specific language" and allow him to add more rules. For existing rules what we expose we have to be careful about, as you rightly pointed.